# Equivalent of Rfc2898DeriveBytes in C++ without using CLR

Tags: c++, cryptography, pbkdf2

What is alternate of Rfc2898DeriveBytes in C++ without using CLR. C# sample is shared below.

```
string clearText="text to sign";
string EncryptionKey = "secret";
byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x48, 0x71, 0x21, 0x6d, 0x21, 0x4c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x72, 0x62, 0x61, 0x62, 0x72 });
    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
        }
        clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: [RFC2898 "C++" site:github.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=RFC2898+"C%2B%2B"+site%3Agithub.com). Also see the [pbkdf2](https://github.com/topics/pbkdf2) tag.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link... most of the code available are not actually in C++.

Comment: So are you commenting there are not enough alternate C++ implementations to chose from? Perhaps the community should find more of them for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC` in OpenSSL.

Both of these functions are [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) function and can be used interchangeability.

**Update:**

Here is a sample code for you for generating similar keys in `C#` and `OpenSSL`.

`C#` side:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string EncryptionKey = "secret";
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x48, 0x71, 0x21, 0x6d, 0x21, 0x4c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x72, 0x62, 0x61, 0x62, 0x72 }, 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", pdb.GetBytes(32)));
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", pdb.GetBytes(16)));
}
```

`OpenSSL` side:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        char secret[] = "secret";
        unsigned char buf[48] = {0,};
        int size = 48;
        unsigned char salt[] = { 0x48, 0x71, 0x21, 0x6d, 0x21, 0x4c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x72, 0x62, 0x61, 0x62, 0x72 };
        PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(secret, strlen(secret), salt, sizeof(salt), 1000, EVP_sha1(), size, buf);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                printf("%d ", buf[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

Just remember in these codes iterations are just 1,000, use at least 100,000 or even 1,000,000.

Comment: thanks for reply... we tried your shared method. Encrypted value (cypher text) from C++ is not getting decoded in C# code. We are using C++ code to encrypt a text and C# to decrypt the text.

Comment: @raj It is better to try solve problem yourself. It took just  minutes to write this. But I update it for you.